# How to approximate the force on a magnet below a coil

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetostatics

```
 o            x
 o            x   Coil with 4 turns
 o            x
 o            x
    _
   | |
   | |            Neodymium magnet
   |_|
```

I need to know the force acting on a neodymium magnet which is placed below a coil. This simple looking problem is actually very complicated, and no data is known about the system, so it can be simplified as necessary.

If the coil has a diameter of about 1 meter, height 150 mm and has 4 turns, and the magnet is 150mm by  50mm, and is placed bellow the coil, close to the edge (see ASCII drawing above).

What is the force on the magnet as a function of current?

Comment: Did you mean to say the magnet is 150m? That seems awfully big... Is the coil circular?

Comment: Oops. It should be 150mm. I've fixed this now. Yes, I am assuming the coil is circular, but it could be another shape (or even multiple coils) if this makes the calculation simpler. I just need to prove a 2000kg mass can be lifted by a big coil. (hopefully without having to add extra iron somewhere). Also, I can increase the number of turns. However the copper is very thick and could possibly even superconducting if need be, so number of coils isn't much of an issue.

Comment: Also the diagram above is a 2D simplified version of the "real system" (In quotes as this doesn't actually exist). However the "real system" has axial symmetry so can be reduced to a 2D problem.

Comment: Axial symmetry? It looks like you have the magnet really far off to one side. And you said it was "close to the edge". Now I really don't understand...

Comment: Just saw the comment about the 2000 kg mass... If you need to make an electromagnet capable of attracting something heavy, I would strongly recommend using a core (rather than air) for the coil. You could always reverse the current to release the object.

Comment: @Floris Unfortunately it has to be an air core. This is one of the few design constraints. Apart from that almost anything could be done. I said before I didn't want to use extra iron to increase the magnetic circuit, but this is just because ideally I want the maths to be as simple as possible.

Comment: @Floris And yes, the magnet is close to the edge but has axial symmetry. The magnet is an annular prism.

Comment: I suggest you update your question - because my understanding of the question has changed considerably from when I first read it and when I wrote my answer. At this point I feel like deleting my answer... but the next person who comes along might be able to help.

Comment: Sorry. I should have been more specific. As I said earlier I just want an aproximation so I left out many details. Please keep your answer, it is useful.  I'll edit the question and make it clear that the added details are an edit.

Answer (score 2):

The field from a bar magnet is approximately a dipole. The field from a coil is approximately a dipole. The force between two dipoles will contain both a torque term, and a attraction / repulsion term - both of which will be proportional to current.

Equations for this can be found at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole#Forces_between_two_magnetic_dipoles

$$F = \nabla (m_2 \cdot B_1)\\
\Gamma = m_2 \times B_1$$

Note that when you get close to the coil, its field is no longer strictly a dipole; instead you might want to think about the field due to just the current closest to the magnet (since the field due to the conductor on the other side will have minimal effect on the force). Thus to estimate this I would probably use the magnetic moment of the bar magnet, and the current due to four linear wire segments (length equal to the diameter) closest to the magnet. The result will be close (within a factor 2 or so).

If you are on axis, the problem is much simplified. Now you can get $B_1$ from an expression for the field of a circular coil - if you have 4 turns, you evaluate this for 4 distances from the center of the coil (z = 0, 50, 100, 150 mm):

$$B_z = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\frac{2\pi R^2 I}{(z^2 + R^2)^{3/2}}$$

The value of $m_1$ is something you have to get from the parameters of the magnet.